# How to call a parameter on click to call a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a function with a param:

This is the function:

```
var showCustomTooltip = function(e, param) {
    param.show(function() {...});
};
```

and this is how I am trying to call it:

`$t1btn.on('click', {param: $('.t1')}, showCustomTooltip);`

But is the error I am getting in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this may indicate that your selector found nothing. Have you placed your code in `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: `console.log` the `param` inside function call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/#passing-data):

```
var showCustomTooltip = function(e, param) {
    param.show(function() {...}); // param is undefined
};
```

Instead:

```
var showCustomTooltip = function(e) {
    e.data.param.show(function() {...});
};
```

jQuery docs example:

```
function greet( event ) {
  alert( "Hello " + event.data.name );
}
$( "button" ).on( "click", {
  name: "Karl"
}, greet );
$( "button" ).on( "click", {
  name: "Addy"
}, greet );
```

Comment: @zmii The docs are referenced in the first line. Is not clear enough?